# Upload via Iframe, IE8/9 access is denied (cross domain)

Tags: javascript, iframe, file-upload, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I'm using an iframe for upload file from a modal pop-up. File is send to the server and respond fine, but when i try to access to the contentDocument of the iframe response i got access is denied. So i try to set the src :

```
iframe[0].src = javascript:'<script>window.onload=function({document.write(\\'<script>document.domain=\\\"" + document.domain + "\\\";<\\\\/script>\\');document.close();};<\/script>'
```

But this does'nt change anything...

Thanks for your help.

UPDATE :

They have both http... I try another scr. But when i view the response iframe with console.log, i see :

```
<iframe name="iframeTransport1411732701469" src="javascript:(function(){document.open();document.domain="localhost";var ed = window.parent.CodeMirror_boilerplate;document.write(ed);document.close();})()">
```

So javascript isn't interpreted... What i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check the protocol of both:
iframe:

```
document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow.document.location.protocol
```

and parent page:

```
document.location.protocol
```

If they are different (http vs https) them it is considered cross reference domain and you cannot change them.

Other thing is an absolute URL - points to another web site.